# Yii framework - pagination data from api

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I'm new to yii, and in the process in learning it. I have successfully made page with checkboxes and these are connected to api. When user clicks on any checkboxes, a set of data will come in and will be displayed on the view. I'd like to paginate these datas but not sure where to start.

This my controller code for my index page. :

```
public function actionIndex()
{   
    $alldata = array();
    $personas = HUB::getResourcePersonas();
    $startupStage = HUB::getResourceStartupStages();
    $industries = HUB::getResourceIndustries();
    $categories = HUB::getResourceCategories();
    $locations = HUB::getResourceGeofocuses();

    if(!empty($_GET) ){


        // do anything you want with your response
        //print_r($response); exit;
        //Yii::import('application.modules.controllers.admin.YourController');

        $persona = '';$stage = '';$stage = '';$cat = '';
        if(isset($_GET['persona'])){
            $persona =  implode(",",$_GET['persona']);
        }
        if(isset($_GET['stage'])){
            $stage =  implode(",",$_GET['stage']);
        }
        if(isset($_GET['industry'])){
            $industry =  implode(",",$_GET['industry']);
        }
        if(isset($_GET['cat'])){
            $cat =  implode(",",$_GET['cat']);
        }
        if(isset($_GET['location'])){
            $location =  implode(",",$_GET['location']);
        }
        $post = [
        'persona' => $persona,
        'stage'=>$stage,
        'industry'=>$industry,
        'location'=>$location,
        'cat'=>$cat,
        'page'=>1

        ];

        $ch = curl_init('http://api-hub.mymagic.my/v1/getResourceAllActive');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

        // execute!
        $response = curl_exec($ch); // print_r($response);

        // close the connection, release resources used
        curl_close($ch);



    }

    $this->render('index',array('personas'=>$personas,'startupStage'=>$startupStage,'industries'=>$industries,'categories'=>$categories,'locations'=>$locations,'data'=>$response));
}
```

My view/ frontend code. Div#list-resource is where the data is displayed ([preview the screenshot of the page](http://i67.tinypic.com/8ygf8n.png)):

```
    <section class="container">
      <div id="">
        <div class="col col-sm-3">
          <div id="sidebar" class="content-main-left">
            <form id="searchResource-form" method="GET" action="<?php echo $this->createUrl('/resource/')  ?>">
              <div class="box-filter rounded-md checkbox checkbox-info">
                <p class="lead">Persona</p>
                <?php $filteredPersona = $_GET['persona']; foreach($personas as $persona): ?>
                <span class="item"><input  <?php if(in_array($persona['slug'],$filteredPersona)){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> id="persona-<?php echo $persona['slug'] ?>" name="persona[]" value="<?php echo  $persona['slug'] ?>" type="checkbox">&nbsp;
  <label for="persona-<?php echo $persona['slug'] ?>"><?php echo $persona['title'] ?></label>
  <i class="btn-popover fa fa-info-circle text-info pull-right" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-content="<?php echo $persona['title'] ?>" data-original-title="" title=""></i>
  </span><br>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

              </div>
              <div class="box-filter rounded-md checkbox checkbox-info">
                <p class="lead">Startup Stages</p>
                <?php $filteredStage = $_GET['stage']; foreach($startupStage as $sst): ?>
                <span class="item">
  <input <?php if(in_array($sst['slug'],$filteredStage)){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> id="stage-<?php echo $sst['slug'] ?>" name="stage[]" value="<?php echo  $sst['slug'] ?>" type="checkbox">&nbsp;
  <label class="" for="stage-<?php echo $sst['slug'] ?>"><?php echo $sst['title'] ?></label>
  <i class="btn-popover fa fa-info-circle text-info pull-right" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-content="<?php echo $sst['title'] ?>" data-original-title="" title=""></i>
  </span><br>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
              </div>
              <div id="box-fiter-cat" class="box-filter rounded-md checkbox checkbox-info">
                <p class="lead">Industry</p>

                <?php $filteredIndustries = $_GET['industry']; foreach($industries as $ind): ?>
                <div id="heading-<?php echo $ind['slug'] ?>" class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                  <span class="item">
  <input  <?php if(in_array($ind['slug'],$filteredIndustries)){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> id="industry-<?php echo $ind['slug'] ?>" type="checkbox" name="industry[]" value="<?php echo $ind['slug'] ?>">
  <label for="industry-<?php echo $ind['slug'] ?>"><?php echo $ind['title'] ?></label>
  </span>
                  <a class="pull-right" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-<?php echo $ind['slug'] ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-<?php echo $ind['slug'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                </div>

                <div id="collapse-<?php echo $ind['slug'] ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php echo $ind['slug'] ?>">
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <?php foreach($ind['childs'] as $ch): ?>
                    <li>
                      <span class="item">
  <input id="subcategory-<?php echo $ind['slug'] ?>-<?php echo $ch['slug'] ?>" name="subcategory[]" value="<?php echo $ind['slug'] ?>.<?php echo $ch['slug'] ?>" type="checkbox">
  <label for="subcategory-<?php echo $ind['slug'] ?>-<?php echo $ch['slug'] ?>"><?php echo $ch['slug'] ?></label>
  </span>
                    </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                  </ul>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

              </div>
              <div id="box-fiter-cat" class="box-filter rounded-md checkbox checkbox-info">
                <p class="lead">Categories</p>
                <?php //print_r($categories); ?>

                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                  <?php $filteredCategories = $_GET['cat1']; $filteredCategories2 = $_GET['cat2']; foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div id="heading-<?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>" class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                      <span class="item"><input  <?php if(in_array($cat['slug'],$filteredCategories)){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> id="cat-<?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>" type="checkbox" name="cat1[]" value="<?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>"> <label for="cat-<?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>"><?php echo $cat['title'] ?></label></span>
                      <a class="pull-right" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-<?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-bizfund"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse-<?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>">
                      <ul class="list-group">
                        <?php foreach($cat['childs'] as $childs_cat): ?>
                        <li>
                          <span class="item">
  <input  <?php if(in_array($childs_cat['slug'],$filteredCategories2)){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> id="cat2-<?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>-<?php echo $childs_cat['slug'] ?>" name="cat2[]" value="<?php echo $childs_cat['slug'] ?>" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cat2-<?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>-<?php echo $childs_cat['slug'] ?>"><?php echo $childs_cat['title'] ?></label>
  </span>
                        </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                      </ul>
                    </div>


                  </div>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="box-fiter-cat" class="box-filter rounded-md checkbox checkbox-info">
                <p class="lead">Location</p>
                <?php $filteredLocation = $_GET['location']; $filteredLocation2 = $_GET['malaysia']; foreach($locations as $location): ?>
                <div id="heading-<?php echo $location['slug'] ?>" class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                  <span class="item"><input  <?php if(in_array($location['slug'],$filteredLocation)){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> id="location-<?php echo $location['slug'] ?>" type="checkbox" name="location[]" value="<?php echo $location['slug'] ?>"> <label for="location-<?php echo $location['slug'] ?>"><?php echo $location['title'] ?></label></span>

                  <a class="pull-right" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-<?php echo $location['slug'] ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-<?php echo $location['slug'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse-<?php echo $location['slug'] ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php echo $location['slug'] ?>">
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <?php foreach($location['childs'] as $childs_location): ?>
                    <li>
                      <span class="item">
  <input <?php if(in_array($childs_location['slug'],$filteredLocation2)){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> id="<?php echo $location['slug'] ?>-<?php echo $childs_location['slug'] ?>" name="malaysia[]" value="<?php echo $childs_location['slug'] ?>" type="checkbox">
  <label for="<?php echo $location['slug'] ?>-<?php echo $childs_location['slug'] ?>"><?php echo $childs_location['title'] ?></label>
  </span>
                    </li>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>



                  </ul>
                </div>


                <?php endforeach; ?>

              </div>
              <noscript>&lt;input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" /&gt;</noscript>
            </form>
            <div id="box-search-keyword" class="box-filter rounded-md checkbox checkbox-info">
              <p class="lead">Search</p>

              <script>
                (function() {
                  var cx = '003080515321755030470:ls0frruy5mm';
                  var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                  gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                  gcse.async = true;
                  gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                  s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
                })();
              </script>
              <div id="___gcse_0">
                <div class="gsc-control-cse gsc-control-cse-en">
                  <div class="gsc-control-wrapper-cse" dir="ltr">
                    <form class="gsc-search-box gsc-search-box-tools" accept-charset="utf-8">
                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="gsc-search-box">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="gsc-input">
                              <div class="gsc-input-box" id="gsc-iw-id1">
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="gs_id50" class="gstl_50 " style="width: 100%; padding: 0px;">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td id="gs_tti50" class="gsib_a"><input autocomplete="off" type="text" size="10" class="gsc-input" name="search" title="search" id="gsc-i-id1" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; border: none; margin: -0.0625em 0px 0px; height: 1.25em; outline: none; background: url(&quot;http://www.google.com/cse/static/images/1x/googlelogo_lightgrey_46x16dp.png&quot;) left center no-repeat rgb(255, 255, 255); text-indent: 48px;"
                                          x-webkit-speech="" x-webkit-grammar="builtin:search" lang="en" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Custom Search"></td>
                                      <td class="gsib_b">
                                        <div class="gsst_b" id="gs_st50" dir="ltr"><a class="gsst_a" href="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"><span class="gscb_a" id="gs_cb50">×</span></a></div>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </div><input type="hidden" name="bgresponse" id="bgresponse"></td>
                            <td class="gsc-search-button"><input type="image" src="https://www.google.com/uds/css/v2/search_box_icon.png" class="gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2" title="search"></td>
                            <td class="gsc-clear-button">
                              <div class="gsc-clear-button" title="clear results">&nbsp;</div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="gsc-branding">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="gsc-branding-user-defined"></td>
                            <td class="gsc-branding-text">
                              <div class="gsc-branding-text">powered by</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="gsc-branding-img"><img src="https://www.google.com/cse/static/images/1x/googlelogo_grey_46x15dp.png" class="gsc-branding-img" srcset="https://www.google.com/cse/static/images/2x/googlelogo_grey_46x15dp.png 2x"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </form>
                    <div class="gsc-results-wrapper-overlay">
                      <div class="gsc-results-close-btn" tabindex="0"></div>
                      <div class="gsc-tabsAreaInvisible">
                        <div class="gsc-tabHeader gsc-inline-block gsc-tabhActive">Custom Search</div><span class="gs-spacer"> </span></div>
                      <div class="gsc-tabsAreaInvisible"></div>
                      <div class="gsc-above-wrapper-area-invisible">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="gsc-above-wrapper-area-container">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td class="gsc-result-info-container">
                                <div class="gsc-result-info-invisible"></div>
                              </td>
                              <td class="gsc-orderby-container">
                                <div class="gsc-orderby-invisible">
                                  <div class="gsc-orderby-label gsc-inline-block">Sort by:</div>
                                  <div class="gsc-option-menu-container gsc-inline-block">
                                    <div class="gsc-selected-option-container gsc-inline-block">
                                      <div class="gsc-selected-option">Relevance</div>
                                      <div class="gsc-option-selector"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="gsc-option-menu-invisible">
                                      <div class="gsc-option-menu-item gsc-option-menu-item-highlighted">
                                        <div class="gsc-option">Relevance</div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="gsc-option-menu-item">
                                        <div class="gsc-option">Date</div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                      <div class="gsc-adBlockInvisible"></div>
                      <div class="gsc-wrapper">
                        <div class="gsc-adBlockInvisible"></div>
                        <div class="gsc-resultsbox-invisible">
                          <div class="gsc-resultsRoot gsc-tabData gsc-tabdActive">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="gsc-resultsHeader">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="gsc-twiddleRegionCell">
                                    <div class="gsc-twiddle">
                                      <div class="gsc-title">Web</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="gsc-stats"></div>
                                    <div class="gsc-results-selector gsc-all-results-active">
                                      <div class="gsc-result-selector gsc-one-result" title="show one result">&nbsp;</div>
                                      <div class="gsc-result-selector gsc-more-results" title="show more results">&nbsp;</div>
                                      <div class="gsc-result-selector gsc-all-results" title="show all results">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="gsc-configLabelCell"></td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div>
                              <div class="gsc-expansionArea"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gsc-modal-background-image" tabindex="0"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-9">

          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Resource Tool</h1>
            <p>The <strong>MaGIC Central resource centre</strong> explore comprehensive collection of over 700 products &amp; services from over 180 organisations available for entrepreneurs. </p>
            <p>This Resource Tool acts as the virtual platform for information and referrals to all resources available within the Malaysian startup ecosystem. Get started, search for resources.</p>

          </div>
          <h1><u>Featured Resources</u></h1>

          <div id="list-resource">
            <?php 
  $jdata = json_decode($data);
  if(!empty($jdata->data)){
  foreach($jdata->data as $jdkey=>$jdvalue){ ?>
            <div class="item row">
              <div class="col-xs-9">
                <h3><a href="<?=$jdvalue->slug ?>"><?=$jdvalue->title ?> </a></h3>
                <?php echo ysUtil::truncate($jdvalue->htmlContent, 250) ?>
                <div class="text-muted margin-top-lg">
                  <?=$jdvalue->resourceCategories[0]->typefor ?> -
                    <?=$jdvalue->resourceCategories[0]->title ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2 pull-right">
                <a href="<?=$jdvalue->slug ?>" class="thumbnail"><img width="125" height="71" src="<?=$jdvalue->imageLogoUrl ?>" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="1innocert_0-259x148"></a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <?php } 

  } ?>




          </div>
```

I'm thinking I should limit the data to about 10 and paginate for the next set of data.

Answer (score 0):

The Yii framework comes with components to make this sort of thing much easier for you. I'm assuming you are using yii1, yii2 has similar components if not.

To begin with, you need to be using a [CDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider) for your queries, this will handling all of the sorting & pagination for you. For your view you should be using a [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView). `CListView supports both sorting and pagination of the data items.` Check the links for code examples.